# If I have a timer in my script, should I clearTimeout on window.onbeforeunload()? Or no need?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, timer

I have a script as per below:

```
var delay;
function delayFire()
{
    delay = setTimeout(autoStatusChange, 2000);
}
```

So should I include a `clearTimeout(delay)` on `window.onbeforeunload()` event? Or actually the browser will clear it automatically when window is closed?

I feel that it is visibility makes no difference if I include or not include the `clearTimeout`.

What would be the common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to not bother cleaning up timers when the browser navigates away, as the browser does it for you already.